# QgsProcessingParameterEnum check all option by default

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I'm building a Processing script with some `QgsProcessingParameterEnum` parameters that accept multiple values.

I cannot find an option to have by default all the options checked when opening the dialog (https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProcessingParameterEnum.html).

Is this option available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just put the default values into a list:

```
defaultValue = [0,1,2], allowMultiple = True
```

So the entire parameter would e.g. look like:

```py
self.addParameter(
     QgsProcessingParameterEnum(
        self.GEOM_PREDICATES, 
        self.tr('Geometric predicate(s)'), 
        ['within','intersects','overlaps','contains','equals','crosses','touches','disjoint'], 
        defaultValue = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 
        allowMultiple = True
    )
)
```

Or automated with a predefined list:

```py
self.mypredicatelist = ['within','intersects','overlaps','contains','equals','crosses','touches','disjoint']
self.mypredicatedefaultvalues = [index for index, predicatestring in enumerate(self.mypredicatelist)]
self.addParameter(
    QgsProcessingParameterEnum(
        self.GEOM_PREDICATES, 
        self.tr('Geometric predicate(s)'), 
        self.mypredicatelist, 
        defaultValue = self.mypredicatedefaultvalues, 
        allowMultiple = True
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to adjust the `defaultValue` like: `defaultValue=[i for i, ii in enumerate(self.time)]` where `self.time` is a list of all my items that fill the enum